# Pylon Camera Emulator Issue: No device is available

Tags: ros, pylons

I'm trying to use Pylon to emulate a camera. I've used the 'Pylon_with_OpenCV.cpp' code provided by Basler which should enable me to acquire and display images.

However, when I run my ROS node, it runs without errors but my emulated camera isn't recognised. I get the following message:
An exception has occurred.
'No device is available or no device contains the provided device info properties.'

I set the environment variable by doing `export PYLON_CAMEMU=1` then running `roscore` in the same window, as instructed, so I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to add to my code or other steps I need to take to set up the emulated camera.

The emulated camera seems to work when I open pylon Viewer but not using pylon API.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it :) I had to add:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

And within my function add:

```
char env[] = "PYLON_CAMEMU=1";
putenv(env);
```